# "Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl."

Tags: android, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

```
{
  "name": "RNNProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.2",
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

graddle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Build Graddle
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' }
```

Comment: I guess React Native 0.59.0-rc.3 solved this issue. https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4757#issuecomment-468133753

Answer (score 28):

I resolved this issue by doing the following steps:

1. in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties change `distributionUrl` value to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`.
2. in android/build.gradle change `classpath` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`.
3. *Optional (if using Metro) create metro.config.js in your project directory and put [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.59-stable/template/metro.config.js) code into it .
4. *Optional (if using Metro) And make sure version of metro in package.json `"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.0"` is right in your packge.json file.
5. remove node_modules folder and run `yarn install`.

Comment: Also have this issue. By using gradle 3.3.0. There is a bug with gradle 3.3.0. It can not resolve the R file. So I can not build my project. I need to downgrade to gradle 3.2.1. Do you have any suggestion about this situation?

Comment: @llch are you using react-native or java? I'm not sure if there is a bug when you upgrade gradle but you can see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error] may help you.

Comment: These steps are not matched with wix documentations. These steps are caused new errors which is about junit test.

Comment: @Omar, I am using react-native. This is a react-native project, and  there is native android view, which is written by Java. I added layout resources and custom java class in Android Studio to the whole project.

Comment: I wonder instead of exact number what should be the general fix. I mean I have distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip and already followed this https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android and still getting similar error

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have react native version updated but your project code is not compatible with react native version.

So you need to do changes manually. You can do it by using react-native upgrade helper

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

Specify your current react-native version and the version would you like to update. You can see the changes that need to be done

Attaching screenshot for help

[image]

Comment: this didn't helped me.

Comment: @praveenseela your comment didn't help me either. Do you mind being more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved my issue by following these steps

1. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json/yarn.lock`.
2. Set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. Add classpath(`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0`) in `android/build.gradle` under `buildscript.dependencies`.
4. Run `yarn`.

You may run into other errors due to gradle upgrade which needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Extra to Omar Al-Howeiti's answer.

Add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```